# Getting sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":" when calling DB Update

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, scrapy

Getting an error when trying to update a column in the db in my pipelines file, set_data_update function. 
What I am trying to do is use the function get_data to return the url and the price, for each url that is returned, call the set_data_update function, where I will swap the existing new_price into old_price, and then put
the new scraped price into new_price. It seems like my call to set_data_update in get_data always runs twice. It should run once, because at the moment I only have one row in the DB for the 2nd URL - 
"[https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07684BPLB)".

Also I see an error in the traceback

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

**products.json**

```
{
"itemdata": [ 
    {   "url": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?`coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview",`
        "title": "coffee_maker_black_and_decker",
        "name": "Cobi Maguire",
        "email": "cobi@noemail.com"
    },
    {   "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10",
        "title": "coffee_maker_hamilton_beach",
        "name": "Ryan Murphy",
        "email": "ryan@noemail.com"
    }
    ]
}
```

> Error Traceback- Traceback (most recent call last):
>     (price_monitor) C:\Users\hassy\Documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor>scrapy crawl price_monitor
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: price_monitor)
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'price_monitor', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'price_monitor.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['price_monitor.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3c0578dfed20521c
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>       ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
>        'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
>        'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>       ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>       ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
>        'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
>       ['price_monitor.pipelines.PriceMonitorPipeline']
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
>       2019-06-15 17:00:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
>       2019-06-15 17:00:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
>       2019-06-15 17:00:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-CM4202S-Programmable-Coffeemaker/dp/B07GWKT87L> from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview>
>       2019-06-15 17:00:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB> from https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10>
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-CM4202S-Programmable-Coffeemaker/dp/B07GWKT87L> (referer: None)
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB> (referer: None)
>       Printing rows
>       ('[https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07684BPLB)', '$37.99')
>       calling func
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'email': 'ryan@noemail.com',
>        'name': 'Ryan Murphy',
>        'price': '$49.99',
>        'title': 'BLACK+DECKER CM4202S Select-A-Size Easy Dial Programmable '
>                 'Coffeemaker, Extra Large 80 ounce Capacity, Stainless Steel',
>        'url': 'h'}
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
>           current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 37, in process_item
>           self.get_data(item)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 60, in get_data
>           self.set_data_update(item, url, new_price)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 88, in set_data_update
>           {'old_price': old_price, 'new_price': item['price']})
>       sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"
>       Printing rows
>       ('[https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07684BPLB)', '$37.99')
>       calling func
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'email': 'ryan@noemail.com',
>        'name': 'Ryan Murphy',
>        'price': '$34.99',
>        'title': 'Hamilton Beach 46310 Programmable Coffee Maker, 12 Cups, Black',
>        'url': 'h'}
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
>           current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 37, in process_item
>           self.get_data(item)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 60, in get_data
>           self.set_data_update(item, url, new_price)
>         File "c:\users\hassy\documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor\pipelines.py", line 88, in set_data_update
>           {'old_price': old_price, 'new_price': item['price']})
>       sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
>       {'downloader/request_bytes': 1888,
>        'downloader/request_count': 5,
>        'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
>        'downloader/response_bytes': 261495,
>        'downloader/response_count': 5,
>        'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
>        'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
>        'finish_reason': 'finished',
>        'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 21, 0, 12, 534906),
>        'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
>        'log_count/ERROR': 2,
>        'log_count/INFO': 9,
>        'response_received_count': 3,
>        'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
>        'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
>        'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
>        'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
>        'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
>        'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
>        'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
>        'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 15, 21, 0, 10, 799145)}
>       2019-06-15 17:00:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

```
(price_monitor) C:\Users\hassy\Documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor>
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import sqlite3


class PriceMonitorPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("price_monitor.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
#        self.store_data(item)
        print("printing items")
        print(item['title'])
        print(item['price'])
        self.get_data(item)
        return item

    def get_data(self, item):
        """ Check if the row already exists for this url """
        rows = 0
        url = ''
        new_price = ''
        self.rows = rows
        self.url = url
        self.new_price = new_price


        self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url =:url""",
                          {'url': item['url']})

        rows = self.curr.fetchone()
        print("Printing rows")
        print(rows)
        rows_url = rows[0]
        new_price = rows[1]

    if rows is not None:
        for item['url'] in rows_url:
            print("calling func")
            self.set_data_update(item, url, new_price)
    else:
        pass

    def set_data_update(self, item, url, new_price):

        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10'
        old_price = new_price
        price = item['price']
        print("printing old price")
        print(old_price)
        print("New Price".format(item['price']))
        self.curr.execute("""update price_monitor SET old_price=: old_price, new_price=: new_price
                              WHERE url=: url""",
                          {'old_price': old_price, 'new_price': price})

        self.conn.commit()
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
```

**Spider**

```
import scrapy
import json
import sys

from ..items import AmazonItem


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'price_monitor'
    newlist = []
    start_urls = []
    itemdatalist = []
    with open('C:\\Users\\hassy\\Documents\\python_venv\\price_monitor\\price_monitor\\products.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        itemdatalist = data['itemdata']

        for item in itemdatalist:
            start_urls.append(item['url'])

    def start_requests(self):

        for item in MySpider.start_urls:

            yield scrapy.Request(url=item, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in MySpider.start_urls:
            scrapeitem = AmazonItem()

            title = response.css('span#productTitle::text').extract_first()
            title = title.strip()
            price = response.css('span#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract_first()

            scrapeitem['title'] = title
            scrapeitem['price'] = price

        for item in MySpider.data['itemdata']:
            url = item['url']
            name = item['name']
            email = item['email']

            scrapeitem['url'] = url
            scrapeitem['name'] = name
            scrapeitem['email'] = email

        yield scrapeitem
```

Comment: I saw a `: url` in the `UPDATE`, which would explain the sqlite error.

Comment: in this? - self.curr.execute("""update price_monitor SET old_price=: old_price, new_price=: new_price
                              WHERE url=: url""",
                          {'old_price': old_price, 'new_price': item['price']})